coefficient order on output of numpy.linalg.lstsq
When using higher order 2D data for the Numpy least squares, what is the order of the output coefficients.
I'm using 4th order and get the following coefficients returned (see tail end of this post).
I can see that the first number ~2936397 is multiplied by x^0 and x^0; basically both at order 0. What is the order for the remainder of the coeffects?
I thought is was the following, but this is not correct.
Coefficient,x-order,y-order
(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), ... (3,4), (4,4)
Thanks in advance.
2936397.6942270664
-15121.957463652841
9.03102972423578
-0.012272870202833481
0.00010249506244899587
-114608.90940722093
468.86962365232756
-0.17328878542700762
-0.00025389866132422223
-4.259024111721344e-08
2460.5890909300783
-7.124697975197747
0.001634958550849398
4.363571901584845e-07
3.193596492720019e-08
-23.96706910671856
0.03889662608251326
8.892484402167611e-07
-3.9098540582926944e-07
-7.002745405770838e-08
0.08027271303336647
-3.2947609724942595e-06
-1.3261478670756333e-07
-1.8548462321632542e-08
2.465621946612373e-07

lstsq has no notion of order. So that is something specific to your application. You need to clarify what are your data, and what you call order in your context. Are you trying to fit 2 variables polynomials  to a set of data? (your text, even if you said x^0 twice, but we can surmise that you meant x^0×y^0, seems to indicate so) Then the coefficents returned are matching the columns of data you provided. If you put x^1y^1 before x^2, then coefficient of x^1y^1 is before coefficient of x^2 in the result. Please provide a [mre] if you want people to answer more acurately.

If order is based on my data input, then let me check that. Thanks for the insight and I'll post more details once fixed.

I found the issue. When I was using higher orders I ran into buffer-overflow when making calculations based on lstsq results. (resulting in negative numbers).
NOTE: I changed from dtype=np.int32 to dtype=np.int64 and this solved my problem.
